# How would you say 'echo chamber' in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

Defined as: an insular communication space where everyone agrees with a certain piece(s) of an ideology and no contrary input is allowed (edited version of [this definition](http://echo-chamber.urbanup.com/4999648#.WPQzg4w9g0Q.twitter))

Comment: Perhaps this should be added to Wikipedia's glossary of business and and management terms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_business_and_management_terms#Low-hanging_fruit

Comment: An echo chamber can also refer to online groups on social media platforms and such.

Answer (score 3):

I am not convinced that *jesviro* or *javiro* are clear in Esperanto, but *jesulo* and *jesemulo* seem to have at least a small amount of traction - in one or two user-edited dictionaries. This calls to mind the term ***jesemulejo***.

- *Mi pensis ke mi bone esploris la aferojn kaj petis opiniojn de aliaj, sed Esperanto Stack Exchange fariĝis malsana **jesemulejo***.

Answer (score 1):

My initial guess would be **Unuecidea Ĉambro** or **Ĉambro de Unueca Ideo**, but these are only to convey the idea if someone hadn't hear the term before.

A direct translation could be **Eĥĉambro" (Eĥa-Ĉambro)** or **"Jesvira Ĉambro"**, as in a room filled with Yes Men. You could also use **Javira Ĉambro**, which I like more since the imagery is better and sounds better (A room full of men going "INDEED!" to someone)

Comment: Do you have any example of "Yes Man" (whatever it is) translated that way to Esperanto?

Comment: I tend to agree with Vanege here -- although reflecting a bit on the suggestion *jesemulejo*, which I might post as a new answer for consideration.

Comment: I don't have any reference, this was just my creative response to this question.

Comment: Why should it be *ĉambro* in the first place?

Comment: I would like to suggest that "creative responses" be kept to a minimum - or at least be clearly labeled as such. This is Esperanto Stack Exchange where people come looking for expert answers. (People voting should also use care to only vote up expert answers.) If you have grammatical errors in your Stack Exchange Introduction, you might want to restrict yourself to answering questions that you actually know the answer to. In this case, the "creative" suggestion started some gears turning, but generally, I have met User301 personally and this is a fairly advanced and creative speaker.

Comment: I like the composition eĥĉambro, sound a bit like "eĥoŝanĝo ĉiuĵaŭde"

Comment: I understand. I shall restrict myself in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything wrong with saying it the way you just did?

- "insular communication space where everyone agrees with a certain piece of an ideology and no contrary input is allowed"

"Mi kredis ke mi profunde pripensis tiajn aferon, sed nun, de la alia flanko de kredo, mi vidas ke mi komunikis nur kun personoj kiuj jam trovis la samajn konkludojn kaj mi neniam aŭdis novajn ideojn."

It seems a little bit too much to expect to find a metaphor which will be immediately clear to people from all different cultures, so it's probably good to spell it out clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I play around with the the idea of calling it *samideanejo* (a place where people with the same idea gather) but the problem is that *samideano* has the specific meaning "Esperantist" in Esperanto.

So perhaps **samismanejo** (where adherents of the same ideology meet) is a *trafa vorto*.

EDIT: I think the word can be shortened to **samismejo** (leaving the *-an-* out, "place of same ideology").